# Data Flow Sink is generating zero byte files at each folder location

Tags: azure-data-factory

In one of the data factory which I am currently using, the data flow sink generates file at every folder location.

Suppose I want to generate a csv as MyData.csv inside Folder1/Folder2/ location.
It does generates MyData.csv inside Folder1/Folder2 location but additionally it generates zero byte file at every Folder location. So my hierarchy looks something like below

```
/Folder1/Folder2 (0 byte file)
/Folder1 (0 byte file)
/Folder1/Folder2/MyData.csv (Desired Output)
```

In old Data factory I was not facing the above issue, I checked the data set and linked service connection. Everything is same. Also checked whether the storage account has a problem, but using the same storage account but different data factory, issue persists. Kindly give suggestions

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/cf6e3731-68d9-4567-9c78-19fe197f4fb3/how-to-fix-adf-creating-empty-files-for-folders?forum=AzureDataFactory)  can help you.

Comment: How did you set the sink destination?